# java convert smalldatetime to date

Tags: java

I'm pulling data with smalldatetime data type from sql, how can I show it in the java section in date (`dd.mm.yyyy`) format

My code ;

```
for (int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) {
    if (liste.get(i).DURUM) {
        String sqlSmallDateTimeString = "2017-10-12 00:00:00";
        liste.get(i).BASTARIH = sqlSmallDateTimeString;

        Timestamp sqlSmallDateTimeValue = Timestamp.valueOf(sqlSmallDateTimeString);

        Date dateValue = new Date(sqlSmallDateTimeValue.getTime());

    }
}
```

Comment: So your date is actually inside a string, right?

Comment: Yes,  inside a string.

Comment: Neither `java.sql.Timestamp` nor `java.util.Date` have the concept of a *format*. Formatting is a separate concern. BTW: You really shouldn't use these old data types. You should be using the modern `java.time` classes like `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate`. You'd format them with `DateTimeFormatter`. If you insist on using these old classes, you can format them with `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: BTW: Given you mention "smalldatetime", I assume the original value came from a database. If so, why do you have it as a string? The JDBC API has methods to get those values either as a `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.time.LocalDateTime` directly.

Comment: `smalldatetime` is not a data type in standard SQL, nor is it a type defined by JDBC. Explain *exacty* what you mean by `smalldatetime`.

Comment: FYI… You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: You cannot determine a timestamp from only a date and a time-of-day. You also need a time zone or offset-from-UTC to get a point on the timeline.

Answer (score 0):

Two common methods, Recommend the second one

```
String sqlSmallDateTimeString = "2017-10-12 00:00:00";
Timestamp sqlSmallDateTimeValue = Timestamp.valueOf(sqlSmallDateTimeString);
Date dateValue = new Date(sqlSmallDateTimeValue.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String format = sdf.format(dateValue);
System.out.println(format); // 12.10.2017
```

second method:

```
String sqlSmallDateTimeString= "2017-10-12 00:00:00";
String inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
 // Parse the input date string to LocalDateTime
 LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(inputDateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputDateFormat));
 String desiredDateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"; // Customize this format as per your needs
 //Format the date using DateTimeFormatter
 String formattedDate = dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(desiredDateFormat));
System.out.println("Formatted date: " + formattedDate);
```

By the way, the lowercase 'mm' represents minutes. Meanwhile, the uppercase "MM" represents the month.

Comment: There is no need to convert a string to a `Date` and then to an `Instant` and then to a `LocalDate`. You can use an appropriate formatter and create a `LocalDate` directly from the string. For example, `LocalDate.parse(sqlSmallDateTimeString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))` and then format that appropriately.

Comment: You are right@MarkRotteveel

Answer (score -3):

If you are not augmenting the value, just parse the text.

```java
String string = "2017-10-12 00:00:00";
string = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(' '));
String[] strings = string.split("-");
string = "%s.%s.%s".formatted(strings[1], strings[2], strings[0]);
```

Output

```
10.12.2017
```